# My jenkins,keycloak and nexus pods are going into CrashLoopBackOff after many restart

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, nexus

Below steps are tried on all 3 pods :

1. I have tried all 3 deleting pods with - kubectl delete pod
2. I have also scale downs the replicas - kubectl scale deployment jenkins-deployment --replicas=0 and scale up again- kubectl scale deployment <> --replicas=1
3. Tried forecfully deletion of pods - kubectl delete pod keycloak-deployment-65ddc94fb7-nptpg --grace-period 0 --force
4. Deleted yml files and applied again - kubectl delete -f nexus.yml
   5)Deleted PV and PVCs.

keycloak yml -

```
   apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      name: keycloak-deployment
      labels:
        component: server
        app: keycloak
        project: gdc-mum
    spec:
      replicas: 1
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          component: server
          app: keycloak
          project: gdc-mum
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            component: server
            app: keycloak
            project: gdc-mum
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: keycloak-server
            image: "jboss/keycloak:8.0.2"
            volumeMounts:
              - name: ldaps-ca
                mountPath: /crt/ldaps-ca.crt
                subPath: ldaps_ca.cer
              - name: keycloak-truststore
                mountPath: /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/keystores/truststore.jks
                subPath: truststore.jks
            env:
              - name: TRUSTSTORE_PASS
                valueFrom:
                  secretKeyRef:
                    key: trustStorePass
                    name: keycloak
              - name: JAVA_OPTS
                value: -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=$(JBOSS_MODULES_SYSTEM_PKGS) -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/keystores/truststore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=$(TRUSTSTORE_PASS)
              - name: DB_VENDOR
                value: postgres
              - name: DB_ADDR
                value: keycloak-postgresql
    #          - name: X509_CA_BUNDLE
    #            value: /crt/ldaps-ca.crt
              - name: DB_USER
                valueFrom:
                  secretKeyRef:
                    key: username
                    name: keycloak-postgres
              - name: DB_PASSWORD
                valueFrom:
                  secretKeyRef:
                    key: password
                    name: keycloak-postgres
              - name: PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING
                value: "true"
              - name: KEYCLOAK_USER
                value: admin
              - name: KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD
                value: admin
            ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
            - containerPort: 8080
            readinessProbe:
              httpGet:
                path: /auth/realms/master
                port: 8080
          volumes:
            - name: ldaps-ca
              configMap:
                name: ldaps-ca
            - name: keycloak-truststore
              configMap:
                name: keycloak-truststore
          nodeSelector:
            beta.kubernetes.io/os: linux
    ---
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: keycloak
      name: keycloak
    spec:
      type: NodePort
      selector:
        component: server
        app: keycloak
        project: gdc-mum
      ports:
       - port: 8080
         name: web
```

nexus.yml

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nexus-vol
  labels:
    app: nexus
    project: gdc-mum
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: manual-iscsi-storage
  volumeName: nexus-pv
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 20Gi
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nexus-deployment
  labels:
    app: nexus
    project: gdc-mum
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nexus
      project: gdc-mum
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nexus
        project: gdc-mum
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nexus
        image: "sonatype/nexus3:3.23.0"
        env:
         - name: NEXUS_CONTEXT
           value: nexus/
        resources:
          requests:
             memory: "1Gi"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8081
        - containerPort: 30000
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /nexus-data
            name: nexus-data
      nodeSelector:
        beta.kubernetes.io/os: linux
      volumes:
      - name: nexus-data
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: nexus-vol
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nexus-service
  labels:
    app: nexus
    project: gdc-mum
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8081
    protocol: TCP
    name: http
  - port: 30000
    nodePort: 30000
    targetPort: 30000
    protocol: TCP
    name: docker-registry
  selector:
    app: nexus
    project: gdc-mum
  type: NodePort
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: nexus-pv
  labels:
    app: nexus
    project: gdc-mum
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 20Gi
  # volumeMode field requires BlockVolume Alpha feature gate to be enabled.
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: manual-iscsi-storage
  iscsi:
    targetPortal: xx.xx.xx.xx:3260
    iqn: iqn.2021-01.com.abc.ad.inmuops02:server
    lun: 5
    fsType: 'xfs'
    readOnly: false
```

jenkins-deployment.yml

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: jenkins-vol
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: iscsi-storage
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: jenkins-deployment
  labels:
    app: jenkins
    project: gdc-mum
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: jenkins
      project: gdc-mum
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: jenkins
        project: gdc-mum
      annotations:
        prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
        prometheus.io/port: "8080"
        prometheus.io/path: "jenkins/prometheus"
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: jenknins
        image: jenkins/jenkins:lts-slim
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        env:
         - name: JENKINS_OPTS
           value: --prefix=/jenkins/
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        - containerPort: 32392
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /var/jenkins_home
            name: jenkins-home
      nodeSelector:
        beta.kubernetes.io/os: linux
      volumes:
      - name: jenkins-home
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: jenkins-vol
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: jenkins-service
  labels:
    app: jenkins
    project: gdc-mum
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    name: http
  - port: 32392
    nodePort: 32392
    targetPort: 32392
    protocol: TCP
    name: agent
  selector:
    app: jenkins
    project: gdc-mum
  type: NodePort
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: jenkins-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  # volumeMode field requires BlockVolume Alpha feature gate to be enabled.
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: iscsi-storage
  iscsi:
    targetPortal: xx.xx.xx.xx:3260
    iqn: iqn.2021-01.com.abc.ad.inmuops02:server
    lun: 3
    fsType: 'xfs'
    readOnly: false
```

keycloak logs -

```
14:04:09,260 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."keycloak-server.war".undertow-deployment: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."keycloak-server.war".undertow-deployment: java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY003325: Failed to construct public org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication()
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:81)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY003325: Failed to construct public org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication()
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ConstructorInjectorImpl.construct(ConstructorInjectorImpl.java:164)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.createProviderInstance(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:2784)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.createApplication(ResteasyDeployment.java:364)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.startInternal(ResteasyDeployment.java:277)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.start(ResteasyDeployment.java:89)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.init(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:119)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.init(HttpServletDispatcher.java:36)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:78)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:305)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.createServlet(ManagedServlet.java:145)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:585)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:556)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.27.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.start(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:598)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:97)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to connect to database
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@8.0.2//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.g
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@8.0.2//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.lock.LiquibaseDBLockProvider.lambda$waitForLock$2(LiquibaseDBLockProvider.java:96)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi-private@8.0.2//org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.suspendJtaTransaction(KeycloakModelUtils.java:682)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@8.0.2//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.lock.LiquibaseDBLockProvider.waitForLock(LiquibaseDBLockProvider.java:94)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@8.0.2//org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication$1.run(KeycloakApplication.java:178)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi-private@8.0.2//org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.runJobInTransaction(KeycloakModelUtils.java:227)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@8.0.2//org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication.startup(KeycloakApplication.java:171)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@8.0.2//org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication.init(KeycloakApplication.java:162)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@8.0.2//org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication.<init>(KeycloakApplication.java:143)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ConstructorInjectorImpl.construct(ConstructorInjectorImpl.java:152)
        ... 31 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS
        at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.4.17.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:159)
        at org.jboss.as.connector@18.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.WildFlyDataSource.getConnection(WildFlyDataSource.java:64)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@8.0.2//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.getConnection(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:366)
        ... 45 more
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS
        at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.4.17.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:690)
        at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.4.17.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:789)
        at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.4.17.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:151)
    
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ031084: Unable to create connection
        at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.4.17.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getSimpleConnection(AbstractPool.java:632)
        at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.4.17.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getConnection(AbstractPool.java:604)
        at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.4.17.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:624)
        ... 50 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
        at org.postgresql.jdbc@42.2.5//org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:292)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc@42.2.5//org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc@42.2.5//org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:195)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc@42.2.5//org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:454)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc@42.2.5//org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:256)
        at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.4.17.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:321)
        ... 57 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: keycloak-postgresql
```

jenkins logs -

```
Running from: /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war
webroot: EnvVars.masterEnvVars.get("JENKINS_HOME")
2021-01-15 14:04:23.648+0000 [id=1]     INFO    org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log#initialized: Logging initialized @455ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog
2021-01-15 14:04:23.793+0000 [id=1]     INFO    winstone.Logger#logInternal: Beginning extraction from war file
2021-01-15 14:04:23.908+0000 [id=1]     INFO    org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server#doStart: jetty-9.4.35.v20201120; built: 2020-11-20T21:17:03.964Z; git: bdc54f03a5e0a7e280fab27f55c3c75ee8da89fb; jvm 1.8.0_242-b08
2021-01-15 14:04:24.074+0000 [id=1]     WARNING o.e.jetty.xml.XmlParser$Handler#fatalError: FATAL@null line:1 col:1 : org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.
2021-01-15 14:04:24.074+0000 [id=1]     WARNING o.e.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext#doStart: Failed startup of context w.@6eebc39e{/jenkins,file:///var/jenkins_home/war/,STOPPED}{/var/jenkins_home/war}
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:400)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1472)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1014)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:842)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:771)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:327)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlParser.parse(XmlParser.java:244)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.Descriptor.parse(Descriptor.java:53)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebDescriptor.parse(WebDescriptor.java:213)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaData.setWebXml(MetaData.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.preConfigure(WebXmlConfiguration.java:55)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.preConfigure(WebAppContext.java:488)
        at winstone.HostConfiguration$1.preConfigure(HostConfiguration.java:167)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:523)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:423)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:387)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
        at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:192)
        at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:369)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at Main._main(Main.java:375)
        at Main.main(Main.java:151)
2021-01-15 14:04:24.081+0000 [id=1]     INFO    o.e.j.s.handler.ContextHandler#doStop: Stopped w.@6eebc39e{/jenkins,null,STOPPED}{/var/jenkins_home/war}
2021-01-15 14:04:24.081+0000 [id=1]     INFO    winstone.Logger#logInternal: Jetty shutdown successfully
java.io.IOException: Failed to start Jetty
        at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:194)
        at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:369)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at Main._main(Main.java:375)
        at Main.main(Main.java:151)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:400)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1472)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1014)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:842)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:771)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:327)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlParser.parse(XmlParser.java:244)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.Descriptor.parse(Descriptor.java:53)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebDescriptor.parse(WebDescriptor.java:213)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaData.setWebXml(MetaData.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.preConfigure(WebXmlConfiguration.java:55)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.preConfigure(WebAppContext.java:488)
        at winstone.HostConfiguration$1.preConfigure(HostConfiguration.java:167)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:523)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:423)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:387)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
        at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:192)
        ... 7 more
2021-01-15 14:04:24.082+0000 [id=1]     SEVERE  winstone.Logger#logInternal: Container startup failed
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:400)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1472)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1014)
        at 
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:842)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:771)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
        at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:192)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to start Jetty
```

Comment: nexus log - container_linux.go:235: starting container process caused "container init exited prematurely"

Comment: Can post output for `kubectl get events --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp`